# Symfony2: Redirect to previous page after login

Tags: php, session, symfony, authentication

I want to do this:

User try to access to a private page (he needs to be logged). When he try to access, he can't access becaouse previously he has to write his credentials. He write his passowrd and log in in the system. I want to the user will be automatically redirected to the page he tried to access.

I put in security.yml

```
use_referer: true
```

And in my first controller I put:

```
$this->getRequest()->headers->get('referer');
```

And I always get the address of the login (.../login.php). Instead of this, I need to obtain for example (.../downloads/test.txt)

I also tried with:

```
$request->getSession()->get('_security.account.target_path');
```

But I get null.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

--- Edit with security.yml ---

```
firewalls:
    frontend:
        pattern:     ^/*
        anonymous:   ~
        simple-form:  
            authenticator: my_authenticator
            check_path: login_check
            login_path: login
            use_referer: true
            failure_path: login_error
        logout:
            path:    logout
            target:  /
            success_handler: my_authenticator
        remember_me:
            key:       mykey
            lifetime:  31536000

        switch_user: { role: ROLE_ADMIN, parameter: _login_as }

access_control:
    - { path: ^/web/login.php, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
    - { path: ^/web/login_error.php, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
    - { path: ^/*, roles: [ROLE_USUARIO, ROLE_RESELLER, ROLE_ADMIN], requires_channel: https }
```

Comment: Can you add the `access_control` part of your `security.yml`?

Comment: yes, I have added to my original post. Thanks.

Comment: If you want the user to redirect to the url *behind* the firewall after successful authentication, you may not need the `use_referer` at all (as pointed out by @colburton). Try removing it.

Comment: `$request->getSession()->get('_security.account.target_path');` will return `null` as your firewall name is 'frontend'. Should be: `$request->getSession()->get('_security.fronted.target_path');`

Comment: Thanks but I removed use_referer the behaviour it's the same. And with $request->getSession()->get('_security.fronted.target_path'); I get always null too. :(

Answer (score 1):

Symfony2 will do this by default. You only specify an url to go to if the user goes directly to the login page (for example by bookmark).

Check this out how to set a "firewall" with this behaviour: [symfony security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html)

Comment: Thanks, but for my this behaviour doesn't work, I added my firewall config in my original post. Thanks.

Comment: check_path and login_path require routes, defined in routes.yml (or elsewhere), not actual files.

Comment: ok, I put check_path and login_path with my routers defined in routing.yml (check_path: login_check and login_path: login) but the system doesn't redirect me to a previous page